# Stream image from MongoDB to browser (MERN stack)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, mongoose, gridfs

I am currently trying to stream a file from my backend (MongoDB) to my frontend (using React).

I have been searching for a few days and have managed to display half of one of my files and the rest will not even show - which seems bizarre as they are all the same format (jpeg). This makes me think I must be uploading them incorrectly but I am not sure where I am going wrong as I am not getting any errors and the uploads.files & uploads.chunks are displaying correctly in my database.

I have also tried changing the readstream into base64 before sending the response to the frontend but it doesn't help, same result as now (i.e. I get half of one image and the others don't display).

Is there anyone who can kindly point out my error(s)?

Backend (imageRoutes.js):

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const multer  = require('multer');
const GridFsStorage = require('multer-gridfs-storage');

const conn = mongoose.createConnection(
    keys.mongoURI,
    { 
        useNewUrlParser: true, 
        useUnifiedTopology: true
    });

let gridFSBucket;
conn.once('open', async () => {
    gridFSBucket = await new mongoose.mongo.GridFSBucket(conn.db, {bucketName: 'uploads'}); 
})

const storage = new GridFsStorage({ 
    db: conn,
    file: (req, file) => {
    if (file.mimetype === 'image/jpeg') {
      return {
        filename: 'file_' + Date.now(),
        bucketName: 'uploads'
      };
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  } 
});

const upload = multer({ storage: storage });

module.exports = app => {
    app.get('/api/img', (req, res) => {
        const readstream = gridFSBucket.openDownloadStreamByName("file_1587913620326");
        console.log(readstream)
        readstream.pipe(res);
    });   

    app.post('/api/upload', upload.array('files', 10), (req, res) => {
            res.send(req.files);
    });
};
```

Frontend:

```
import React from 'react';

class ImgDisplay extends React.Component {

    render() {
        return(
            <div className="flex w-100 justify-center">
                <img className="w-30 h-30" src="/api/img" alt="image1" />
            </div>
        )
    }   
}

export default ImgDisplay;
```

P.S. I have setup a proxy so that whenever /api/* is visited my server is targeted.

Comment: Try setting the `Content-Type` response header before piping the response

Comment: Thanks for responding, I really appreciate it. I have tried adding res.set({'content-type': 'image/jpeg','content-disposition': 'inline'}) (I've tried both inline and attachment) before const readstream = ... but didn't help :/

Comment: Verify that you are receiving a file correctly by inspecting the html and opening the resulting image link in a new tab and not getting an 400-500 error

Comment: I had to set contentType: 'binary/octet-stream' in const storage...not quite sure why...